# Capturing iBeacon messages for later use

Tags: ios, ibeacon

have a quick question on iBeacons.
Is there a way the user can capture messages they receive when they
are in a particular range to a beacon? Lets say an iBeacon app is being used
in a retail store, the user walks close to a particular beacon and
gets a message prompt and likes it but when he walks away it goes away
and another message appears. Is there a way for the user to capture
which messages they like and look at it later on even when they are
not in the store r within range to a beacon?

Thank you very much

Comment: In an app you're creating? Or in general? Without opening the app?

Comment: within the app. Like lets say within a UI text field or even just as notifications. The information vanishes once the user leaves a particular zone. How can the user capture this without having to go back to a particular beacon to receive the information again?

Comment: If you design your own app, you get region monitoring notifications on entering an iBeacon region. In that you can handle all what you want related to the notification, also saving the notification and whatever other stuff

Comment: Ok just wanted to see if this is possible because there is no documentation on saving the updates you get from region monitoring

Answer (score 5):

The iBeacon itself doesn't send any messages to the end user.  It just makes a three-part numeric identifier available to the app when the iBeacon is visible through the Monitoring or Ranging APIs.  Any messaging directly displayed to the user (through a text field or a notification or whatever) always originates from the app itself, in the use case you describe triggered by the iBeacon being detected.

Because the messages always originate from the app and not the iBeacon, you can simply program the app to save off any messaging for later viewing by the end user.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve doesn't seem to be directly related to ibeacons.

It's more about how you will design your app and features. Surely you can save any kind of messages/notifications for posterior use/visualisation. For example you can store them on a server database or locally using iOS user-defaults of your app.

The same thing happens when you receive SMS or email. An app stores them so you can see later, including the time you received and who sent you.